# ¿Para que sirve que una variabel sea static en java?

Tags: java

Alguien podría explicármelo fácilmente pues estoy tomando un curso y el profesor lo explica con demasiado tecnicismo, si no he entendido mal es como una variable cuyo valor es igual en todos los objetos, pero la verdad no estoy muy seguro, AYUDENME PLIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una variable estática es básicamente una variable a la que se puede acceder sin necesidad de crear un objeto, esta variable pertenece a la clase y no al objeto. No se si es demasiado técnica mi explicación o se entiende fácilmente.

Este acceso tiene sus ventajas e inconvenientes, como ventaja se puede acceder a ese dato que contiene la variable de forma mas rápida y mas sencilla, con menos código ya que no debes instanciar un nuevo objeto de esa clase para ello. Por el lado negativo, estas rompiendo con el paradigma POO.

Comment: Por qué rompe el paradigma de la POO?

Comment: @BetaM rompe el paradigma de OO porque sobre este tipo de miembros no se pueden aplicar los conceptos o técnicas relacionadas con este paradigama como herencia y polimorfismo. Además de que el propio paradigma define que el software está compuesto de una serie de objetos con estado que intercambian mensajes entre ellos; y los miembros estáticos no forman parte de los objetos.

Comment: Lo comprendo E.Betanzos solo pregunte para que el usuario pueda mejorar su aporte indicando las razones lo cual daría más contexto a su afirmación

Comment: No obstante no creo que sea negativo que este tipo de miembros rompan con el OOP, puesto que nos proporcionan una serie de características que muy útiles.

Comment: @BetaM te entiendo, quizás pueda usar lo que comenté para enriquecer su respuesta.

Comment: @BetaM ¿ O sea que sirve para ahorrarse el instanciar un objeto no ? ¿Y eso que dije de que es como una variable cuyo valor es igual en todos los objetos es  falso no?

Comment: @CarlosPerandelBrio **1. Respuesta:** Si.  **2. Respuesta:** Es falso, porque la variable estática no forma parte de la instancia actual (es decir, del objeto creado).

Comment: @MrDave1999 Muchas gràcias por la ayuda.